# Different animation behaviour for second background-image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a sidebar menu with animations and trying to do as much as possible with css only. If it's not possible, JS / JQuery is ok as well.

My problem is, I've got a `<span></span>` element with two background images and I wanna have different animation behaviours for them. The first one should rotate and increase it's size according to the span's size, the second one should NOT rotate and stay with the same size as before, but should only appear after the animation has finished.

Is it possible to have kompletely different animations on one element for each background image? If yes, how?

Here's my code so far:

The list is done with an unordered list, each `<li></li>` should contain one menu-item

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a class="menu-item-link" href="#"><span class="menu-item">1</span>Active or hovered Menu</a>
    </li>
    <li><li>
</ul>
```

Some CSS for it with animation keyframes

```
.menu-item-wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  clear: both;
}

.menu-item-link {
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-item {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-image: url("hexagon.svg"), url("mars.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.menu-item:hover {
  animation-name: menuAnimation;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    color: transparent;
}

@keyframes menuAnimation {
    from {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    to {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        transform: rotate(210deg);
    }
}
```

[And a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hoargarth/q4ufL9zu/34/)

And that's how it should look like after the animation has finished (the planet image and link text should only be visible after the animation has finished)

[image]

Comment: I dont get what is the animation you expect for the secon element

Comment: I don't really want an animation for it, but since I'm rotating the span, I need to rotate the second background counter-clockwise, so it won't rotate. Same with resize i guess.

Comment: You could use the great GSAP library https://greensock.com/gsap
since you need to trigger an animation after the first one has finished

Comment: @t3__rry looks interesting, I'll try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
.menu-item-wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  clear: both;
}

.menu-item-link {
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-item {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu-item::before {
  content: "";
  background-color: green;
  background-image: url("hexagon.svg"); /*added bg color because of the missing image*/
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.menu-item::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url("mars.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0s 0.5s ease;
}

.menu-item:hover::before {
  animation-name: menuAnimation;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transform: rotate(210deg);
}

.menu-item:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

https://codepen.io/zothynine/pen/GQQdLp

Comment: Yup, that's exactly I was looking for. Temani Afif suggested a similar solution, but I guess your's is better since there's no need for keyframes. Makes the css file a lot more compact. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

And idea is to split the element into two element using a pseudo element and then you can animate both of them separately and simultaneously:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.menu-item-link {
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-item {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-image: url("https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/247374/Mars.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}

.menu-item:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index:1;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;utf8;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iaXNvLTg4NTktMSI/Pgo8IS0tIEdlbmVyYXRvcjogQWRvYmUgSWxsdXN0cmF0b3IgMTYuMC4wLCBTVkcgRXhwb3J0IFBsdWctSW4gLiBTVkcgVmVyc2lvbjogNi4wMCBCdWlsZCAwKSAgLS0+CjwhRE9DVFlQRSBzdmcgUFVCTElDICItLy9XM0MvL0RURCBTVkcgMS4xLy9FTiIgImh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnL0dyYXBoaWNzL1NWRy8xLjEvRFREL3N2ZzExLmR0ZCI+CjxzdmcgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB4bWxuczp4bGluaz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMTk5OS94bGluayIgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4xIiBpZD0iQ2FwYV8xIiB4PSIwcHgiIHk9IjBweCIgd2lkdGg9IjMycHgiIGhlaWdodD0iMzJweCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDQ4NS42ODggNDg1LjY4OCIgc3R5bGU9ImVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kOm5ldyAwIDAgNDg1LjY4OCA0ODUuNjg4OyIgeG1sOnNwYWNlPSJwcmVzZXJ2ZSI+CjxnPgoJPGc+CgkJPHBhdGggZD0iTTM2NC4yNjksNDUzLjE1NUgxMjEuNDE2TDAsMjQyLjg0NEwxMjEuNDE2LDMyLjUzM2gyNDIuODUzbDEyMS40MTksMjEwLjMxMkwzNjQuMjY5LDQ1My4xNTV6IE0xMzEuOTA1LDQzNC45OTdoMjIxLjg3OCAgICBsMTEwLjkzOS0xOTIuMTUyTDM1My43ODMsNTAuNjkxSDEzMS45MDVMMjAuOTY2LDI0Mi44NDRMMTMxLjkwNSw0MzQuOTk3eiIgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRkZGRiIvPgoJPC9nPgo8L2c+CjxnPgo8L2c+CjxnPgo8L2c+CjxnPgo8L2c+CjxnPgo8L2c+CjxnPgo8L2c+CjxnPgo8L2c+CjxnPgo8L2c+CjxnPgo8L2c+CjxnPgo8L2c+CjxnPgo8L2c+CjxnPgo8L2c+CjxnPgo8L2c+CjxnPgo8L2c+CjxnPgo8L2c+CjxnPgo8L2c+Cjwvc3ZnPgo=);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.menu-item:hover {
  animation-name: anime1;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  color: transparent;
}
.menu-item:hover::before {
  animation-name: anime2;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes anime1 {
  from {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    transform: rotate(210deg);
  }
}
@keyframes anime2 {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    opacity:0;
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(-210deg);
    opacity:1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-item-wrapper">
  <a class="menu-item-link" href="#"><span class="menu-item">1</span>Active or hovered Menu</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it's working as well. However I've choosen Zothy Nine's solution, because it makes things a lot more compact.

Comment: @Hoargarth no problem :) at least you get the trick ;) then transition or animation it's up to you